# Synchronization using System V semaphore of 3 process

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore

I have 3 processes, i want to synchronize using system v semaphore.
Process 1,2,3 will write data in single file.

Process 1 write A to I,
Process 2 write a to i,
Process 3 write 1 to 9.

Output i am expecting Aa1Bb2Cc3Dd4Ee5Ff6Gg7Hh8Ii9.

Process 1

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int id,ret,fd;  
    char i;

    struct sembuf v;

    id=semget(8, 5, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    if(id <0)
    {
        printf("wrong\n");
    }
    fd= open("sample1", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT,0644);

    v.sem_num = 1;
    v.sem_op = 0;
    v.sem_flg = 0;

    semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 0);   
    semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 0);   
    semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 0);

    for(i='A';i<='I';i++)
    {
        semop(id,&v,1);
        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 1);       

        write(fd, &i, 1);

        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 0);
        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
    }

    printf("Done...\n");    
}
```

Process 2

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int id,ret,fd;  
    char i;

    struct sembuf v;

    id=semget(8,5, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    if(id <0)
    {
        printf("wrong\n");
    }
    fd= open("sample1", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0644);

    v.sem_num = 2;
    v.sem_op = 0;
    v.sem_flg = 0;

    for(i='a';i<='i';i++)
    {
        semop(id,&v,2); 
        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 1);   
        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 1);

        write(fd, &i, 1);

        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 0);
        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 1);
    }

    printf("Done...\n");    
}
```

Process 3

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int id,ret,fd;  
    char i;

    struct sembuf v;

    id=semget(8,5, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    if(id <0)
    {
        printf("wrong\n");
    }
    fd= open("sample1", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT,0644);

    v.sem_num = 3;
    v.sem_op = 0;
    v.sem_flg = 0;

    for(i='1';i<='9';i++)
    {
        semop(id,&v,3); 
        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 1);   
        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 1);

        write(fd, &i, 1);

        semctl(id, 1, SETVAL, 0);
        semctl(id, 2, SETVAL, 1);
        semctl(id, 3, SETVAL, 1);
    }

    printf("Done...\n");    
}
```

Expected output is Aa1Bb2Cc3Dd4Ee5Ff6Gg7Hh8Ii9. but i am not getting correct output. Please can one help to get out of this problem?

Which sempahore is good? system V semaphore or POSIX semaphore ?
I am new to synchronization process. Please me help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for which semaphore implementation to prefer, there are reasons why POSIX devised its own instead of just going forward with SysV semaphores.  SysV semaphores do have features that the POSIX ones lack, but I'm generally inclined to recommend the POSIX flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have several problems, both in strategy and in implementation.

**First**, the usual basic mechanism for gating program / thread progress via a SysV semaphore is for the thread whose progress is to be controlled to use `semop()` to attempt to decrement the semaphore.

```
struct sembuf sb = { .semnum = 1, .sem_op = -1 };
int rval = semop(semid, &sb, 1);
// handle any error ...
```

This will block until the semaphore's value is great enough to proceed (given that it can never go below zero).  To allow that thread to proceed, some other thread, possibly in a different process, will use `semop()` to *increment* the same semaphore:

```
struct sembuf sb = { .semnum = 1, .sem_op = 1 };
int rval = semop(semid, &sb, 1);
// handle any error ...
```

Additionally, this approach means that a thread managing to lock the semaphore (by decrementing its value) automatically reduces the opportunities for other threads (or itself) to lock it, too.  When you arrange it so that semaphore values will never exceed 1, this makes decrementing a semaphore function much like locking a mutex, and incrementing one function like unlocking a mutex.

Note well that `semctl()` is not involved in any of these bits (though it will be involved in setting up the semaphore set beforehand).  You should view `semctl()` as an administrative interface for managing semaphores, not as an interface for ordinary semaphore operations.

**Second**, you have a problem with semaphore initialization.  It is performed only by process 1, but you present nothing that ensures that process 1 will complete its initialization before the other processes start trying to use the semaphore set.  This turns out to be one of the most problematic aspects of SysV semaphores.

One way to get around that is to have a launcher that sets up and initializes the semaphore set, and only then launches the three processes that actually use it (none of which then need to initialize it).

If you can rely on the semaphore set initially not to exist (and that's problematic for you because you use a fixed key and never remove the semaphore set) then your processes can use the `O_EXCL` flag in addition to `O_CREAT` when they call `semget()`.  That will succeed only in one of the processes, which then can take responsibility for initializing the semaphores.  The others perform a new `semget()` without `O_EXCL`, and then wait for the initialization to be complete.  They can do that by polling `semctl()` with the `IPC_STAT`, watching for the semaphore's `otime` to become nonzero, which will happen the first time the initializing thread performs a `semop()`.

**Third**, there are multiple small oddities in your code, including

- You request a 5-member semaphore set, but only use 3.
- Members of a semaphore set are numbered from 0, but the lowest semaphore number you use is 1.
- Except when you use `IPC_PRIVATE` as your semaphore key, it is usual to obtain a key via `ftok()` instead of using a fixed key id.  This helps avoid key collisions.
- When given, the fourth argument to `semctl` should be a `union` (which you are obliged to define yourself, consistent with the documentation), but you are passing `int`s.  If that seems to work as you expected then it's only because you've gotten lucky.
- After the last process is done with the semaphore, you should remove it.  You can do that by performing the `IPC_RMID` action with `semctl()`, or, if necessary, after the fact by running an appropriate `ipcrm` command from a shell.
- You should check the return code of *every* function call that provides one, except where you genuinely do not care whether it succeeded.